# Can the PIC32 post to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a website, and mobile website that query a MySQL database.  The PIC32 is able to detect temperatures and humidities and post them as HTML.  Is is possible to post them to an already existing PHP file that can post those values to the database?  If not, can I write directly PHP code that can post the variables to the database?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  You could encode them as name value pairs:

```
http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?temp=100&humidity=75
```

Then use the MySQL library to put these in the database, in your PHP script:

```
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "pass");
mysql_select_db("test");

$temperature = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['temp']);
$humidity= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['humidity']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO exampledata
(temp, humidity) VALUES('$temperature', '$humidity' ) ") ;
```

Of course, keep in mind you should check your values for security if this is a public site.

Comment: That'll work, but please don't forget to *always* use mysql_real_escape string on client-side input data to avoid SQL injection problems!

Comment: Also, if you didn't want to use PHP and your database had its port open to the world, you could send your queries directly to that.  Open a socket to port 3306 (usually) and send the query directly.

Comment: @Daan: Exactly; that was my last sentiment in the answer as well.

Comment: That's what I thought, but just to make sure he understood what you meant by that. You may want to actually edit that into your code; code here on StackOverflow is often used as an example by people coming in from Google who don't read the full threads and just go with whatever works :)

As to the socket: that would work, of course, but I can't imagine that would be easier to implement on a PIC32 system...not sure though, never programmed for one :)

Comment: @Daan: Great suggestion; edited.  As far as the socket, it would depend on what else is going on in the PIC32, whether he has the sockets libraries all set up, and is not comfortable with PHP.  I think the PHP way would be the easiest though, you are correct.